# Is anything wrong with my PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, atmega, schematics, xbee, gps

I am designing a PCB and I just want to make sure nothing is wrong before I send it off to the fab house. If one of you knowledgeable stack exchangers could give me some feedback, I would really appreciate it.

Here is the schematic :
[image]

and here is the board :
[image]

I don't have enough reputation to post a link to the eagle files, so if anyone wants them, 
just let me know.

Comment: What does your board do?

Comment: All supply pins on each chip should be decoupled close to the device.

Comment: No earth plane means poor emc performance.

Comment: 1. In the schematic, you're missing the "VCC" label at the output of your voltage regulator (on the + side of C2)

Comment: 2. The GND pin of your USB connector should be labeled "GND", not "GND1". It needs to be connected with all the other grounds on your circuit.

Comment: 3. I'm not familiar with the ATmega microcontrollers, but I'm pretty sure pin AREF shouldn't be left floating; probably must be connected to VCC. See the datasheet of the microcontroller for, it should provide a minimum schematic for the uC to work properly, including some decoupling capacitors.

Comment: 4. The BLUE LED1 is connected the other way around

Comment: There's a lot wrong with your schematic (consequently, your layout too), but I don't have the time to go through all of it right now. If someone wants to provide a more detailed answer, feel free to include my comments as well

Comment: Some very good finds there @m.Alin.

Might I suggest someone does a design review of your schematic  before you look at the PCB layout anyfurhter. In just the 10 minutes m.Alin spent looking he found some mistakes that certain mean your circuit isn't going to function at all

Answer (score 1):

*Change resistor for RESET pin to 10K.

*Add a 100nF cap between AREF and GND pin.

*Add 100nF capacitor between each VCC pin of your ICs and GND.

*Connect GND pin of USB to GND.

*Connect VOS of TPS62172 to VCC!!!!

*I can't find GPSTX label! where it should be connected!

*Connect LED1 to GND.

- Your L2 has no value, it should be 33nH.

I think revise your design...

This maybe useful:
https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/GPS/Modules/Skytraq-Venus634FLPx_DS_v051.pdf

Comment: Sorry. I redid the schematic in eagle after I made the board, so I didn't check that the nets were connected together. You will see that if you look at the PCB, most of your points were addressed. Led 1 does not connect to GND, but rather VCC.

Comment: about LED1, then you should reverse it's direction.I first look at your schematic that is faster to detect problems, then I suggest strongly that add mentioned capacitors near ICs. it was better that you attach most current schematic into this post, anyway.

Comment: @Mathieupasquet The schematic and PCB designs should be exactly the same! Otherwise, what's the point in having a schematic?

Comment: Posting a schematic and PCB that don't match for design review is a waste of everyone's time. Don't do that, use your tools to verify that schematic and PCB match and if they don't fix them before posting for review.